# How to request refresh and access tokens from Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, oauth-2.0

I have been attempting to follow the Spotify Authorization Guide to receive an access token from the Spotify API for a school project. I am following the Authorization Code Flow and have already had my application prompt the user to login to authorize access. I am pretty confident I already have the authorization code that is to be swapped for an access token. According to the authorization guide, *"When the authorization code has been received, you will need to exchange it with an access token by making a POST request to the Spotify Accounts service..."*

This is what I am trying:

```
const _getToken = async (code) => {

    const result = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' : 'Authorization: Basic ' + encode(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET)
        },
        body: {
            'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
            'code' : code,
            'redirect_uri' : 'exp://localhost:19000/--/'
        }
    });

    const data = await result.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data.access_token;
```

This is what is being logged in the console:

> > Object {    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",    "error_description":
> > "grant_type parameter is missing",  }

This is confusing because the Spotify Authorization Guide seems to suggest that the `grant_type` parameter should be `authorization_code` (screenshot of documentation below).

[Spotify Authorization Guide -- documentation for requesting access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7odTa.png)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!